# Facing issue while connecting Quickbook Premier Accountant 2017 with web connector

Tags: php, quickbooks

When I am trying to connect my Quickbook Premier Accountant 2017, I am facing some issue. Error code is:

> QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
>   Client found response content type of 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with an empty response. See QWCLog for more details. Remember to turn logging on.

Please suggest me what to change.

In Quickbook Library I am getting this error:

[image: error]

And I am using `docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector/config.php` file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error your posted indicates that your `$dsn` database connection string is incorrect or badly formatted.

Post your code and `$dsn` string (you can `xxx` out the password if you want) if you need additional help.